# Selenium Webdriver: download files on firefox using DesiredCapabilities class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there an alternative to firefox profile to download files, i.e. through desiredcapability on selenium webdriver?

I want to download files from a website but through desiredcapabilities.

So one piece of code is applicable accross all the browsers.

Comment: Please explain what is not working, and explain in detail what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could create a AugmenterProvider  and pass it to the Augmenter class but I have not done so and its beyond my skill.